# how to detect collision by box2d in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have two sprites:one character sprite and another one is obstacle sprite. obstacle sprite is child of another sprite called bgSprite which is continuously moving. How can i detect collision between them. 
I am using CGRECTINTESECTRECT but its not looking realistic. I heard about box2d but i have not use it yet. Here is some code:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]     
addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"BoyRunAnimation.plist"];

CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode     
batchNodeWithFile:@"BoyRunAnimation.png"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet];        

self._character = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Boy_Run_0003.png"];
self._character.position = ccp(80, 150);
[spriteSheet addChild:self._character];
[self boyRunningAnimation];
```

//obstacles

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
int xPos=500+500*i;
if (xPos<2*_roadImage1.contentSize.width)
{
    CCSprite *obstacle=[CCSprite node];
    obstacle.textureRect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, _roadImage1.contentSize.height);
    obstacle.color=ccc3(255, 255,255);

    if (xPos <= _roadImage1.contentSize.width)
    {
        obstacle.position=ccp(xPos, _roadImage1.contentSize.height/2);

        [_roadImage1 addChild:obstacle z:0 tag:1];
    }
    else
    {
        obstacle.position=ccp(xPos-_roadImage1.contentSize.width, 60);

        [_roadImage2 addChild:obstacle z:0 tag:2];
    }
    [obstacleArray addObject:obstacle];
 }    
 }
```

in update method:

```
  CCRect obstacleBox = [obstacle boundingBox];
  CCPoint obstaclePosition = obstacleBox.origin;
  obstaclePosition = [[obstacle parent] convertToWorldSpace:obstaclePosition];
  obstaclePosition = [[self._character parent] convertToNodeSpace:obstaclePosition];
  obstacleBox.origin = obstaclePosition;
  if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self._character.boundingBox, obstacleBox))
  {
    isTouchActive=NO;
    NSLog(@"collision");
   }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Check the Box2D manual http://box2d.org/manual.pdf and follow a Box2D tutorial: https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=cocos2d+box2d+tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=A1tVUpqbCa6p7Aam64HIBg#q=cocos2d-iphone+box2d+tutorial&rls=en

Answer (score 1):

If you are using box2d, then the collision detection is handled in the Box2d engine when it processes the world update.  This detects the collision between fixtures on the body, not the body itself.  So if your body is made of a group of fixtures, you can get detection down to a very small part of the body to make the placement of the explosion (or whatever) look good.

The simple answer is to derive a class from b2ContactListener and tell the b2World you want to use it.  The example from the manual looks like this:

```
class MyContactListener : public b2ContactListener 
{
public:
void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) { /* handle begin event */ }
void EndContact(b2Contact* contact) { /* handle end event */ }
void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold) { /* handle pre-solve event */ }
void PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse)
{ /* handle post-solve event */ } 
};
```

You register it using b2World::SetContactListener(...) on an instance of your derived class.

HOWEVER, it is not quite as simple as that.  My experience is that for a single "collision" you get multiple calls to your class during the world update.

Below is a more complete solution.  In this, each "thing" in the world has a b2Body and the user tag points back to the root class (called Entity).  It accumulates a list of collisions and checks to see if each new event references a pair that was already seen, filtering out duplicates.  After the world update NotifyCollisions is called to send messages to the entities that a collision has occurred and they need to do something about it.

This is part of a larger code base; feel free to ask any questions if you need clarification because the code is not here.

```
class EntityContactListener : public ContactListener
{
private:
   GameWorld* _gameWorld;
   EntityContactListener() {}

   typedef struct 
   {
      Entity* entA;
      Entity* entB;
   } CONTACT_PAIR_T;

   vector<CONTACT_PAIR_T> _contactPairs;

public:
   virtual ~EntityContactListener() {}

   EntityContactListener(GameWorld* gameWorld) :
      _gameWorld(gameWorld)
   {
      _contactPairs.reserve(128);
   }

   void NotifyCollisions()
   {
      Message* msg;
      MessageManager& mm = GameManager::Instance().GetMessageMgr();

      for(uint32 idx = 0; idx < _contactPairs.size(); idx++)
      {
         Entity* entA = _contactPairs[idx].entA;
         Entity* entB = _contactPairs[idx].entB;

         //DebugLogCPP("Contact Notification %s<->%s",entA->ToString().c_str(),entB->ToString().c_str());

         msg = mm.CreateMessage();
         msg->Init(entA->GetID(), entB->GetID(), Message::MESSAGE_COLLISION);
         mm.EnqueueMessge(msg, 0);

         msg = mm.CreateMessage();
         msg->Init(entB->GetID(), entA->GetID(), Message::MESSAGE_COLLISION);
         mm.EnqueueMessge(msg, 0);         
      }
      _contactPairs.clear();
   }

   void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold)
   {

   }

   // BEWARE:  You may get multiple calls for the same event.
   void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
   {
      Entity* entA = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      Entity* entB = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      //DebugLogCPP("Begin Contact %s->%s",entA->ToString().c_str(),entB->ToString().c_str());
      if(entA->GetGroupID() == entB->GetGroupID())
      {  // Can't collide if they are in the same group.
         return;
      }

      assert(entA != NULL);
      assert(entB != NULL);

      for(uint32 idx = 0; idx < _contactPairs.size(); idx++)
      {
         if(_contactPairs[idx].entA == entA && _contactPairs[idx].entB == entB)
            return;
         // Not sure if this is needed...
         if(_contactPairs[idx].entA == entB && _contactPairs[idx].entA == entB)
            return;
      }
      CONTACT_PAIR_T pair;
      pair.entA = entA;
      pair.entB = entB;
      _contactPairs.push_back(pair);
   }

   // BEWARE:  You may get multiple calls for the same event.
   void EndContact(b2Contact* contact)
   {
      /*
      Entity* entA = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      Entity* entB = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      DebugLogCPP("End Contact %s->%s",entA->ToString().c_str(),entB->ToString().c_str());
       */
   }
};
```

Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

In COCOS2D-X

First of all you have make body for the your sprite. And move the body according to sprite.

You have to extends your class with b2contactlistener. It have few method which you have to implement in your code.
You can read this article for for clerarity
[Box2D for Collision Detection with Cocos2D-X | Cocos2d-x](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606)